# how to pass variable from html template to view method in django via url

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to pass a variable from html template to my view method in django so that i can use it in the python view method.

Below is my html code:

```
<li><a href="{%url 'Automation:rollbackAAI' router_hostname %}">Rollback</a>
```

My URL  mapping:

```
url(r'rollbackAAI/(?P<router_name>[a-z]+)$',views.rollbackAAI, name='rollbackAAI'),
```

My views.py:

```
def rollbackAAI(request, router_name = None, *args, **kwargs):
    print (router_name)
```

However while loading the html template it's giving NoReserveMatch error:

```
Reverse for 'rollbackAAI' with arguments '('a2router',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['vpesat/rollbackAAI/(?P<router_name>[a-z]+)$']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router name has a number in it, which doesn't match your regex. You should probably use `\w`, which matches all alphanumeric characters.

```
r'rollbackAAI/(?P<router_name>\w+)$'
```